# how to make this module run which the user press the button and closes the main module and run the other module that i imported

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import SignUp # name of the module 

class SignIN_SignOut:

    def __init__(self,master): 
        self.master = master

        master.title("Login and Logout")

        #some code

        self.signup_btn = Button(master,text="Sign Up",command=SignUp.Signupbtn) #here is the problem
        self.signup_btn.place(x=200,y=300)

#end of the code

def main():

    root = Tk()

    root.state('zoomed') # for full screen

    firstPhase = SignIN_SignOut(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code above? Do you want the main window to close when you call `SignUp.Signupbtn`?

Comment: @TheLizzard thnx for helping, when the user click the sign up button, i wants the main program to closed and open the signup class code. So basically I am importing the sign up class file and then when the user click sign up it runs the sign up class file

Comment: Instead of `command=SignUp.Signupbtn` define your own function that calls `root.destroy()` and then `SignUp.Signupbtn()`. But you will need to add `global root` to the start of your `main` function.

Comment: Can you explain more by just type for my the line code that needed to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
import SignUp # name of the module 

class SignIN_SignOut:

    def __init__(self,master): 
        self.master = master

        master.title("Login and Logout")

        #some code

        self.signup_btn = Button(master,text="Sign Up",command=self.start_signup) #here is the problem
        self.signup_btn.place(x=200,y=300)

    def start_signup(self):
        root.withdraw() # Hides the window
        SignUp.Signupbtn()
        # When ever the sign up is done call:
        # root.deiconify() # shows the window

#end of the code

def main():
    # Make root a global variable
    global root
    root = Tk()

    root.state('zoomed') # for full screen

    firstPhase = SignIN_SignOut(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```